# phonegap ios Get the address url of the phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

Im using Phonegap in AppDelegate.m class in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method I redirect the app to the url as following:

```
 NSString * url = [userDefaults stringForKey:@"url_preference"];
    NSURL * urlRedirect = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlRedirect];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self.viewController.webView loadRequest:request];
```

In the MainViewController.m I have a few buttons that by clicking on them the app redirect to other urls. 
How can I get the address url that my app in the Phonegap platform is redirected to?

Answer (score 1):

Outside the `MainViewController.m`

```
self.viewController.webView.request.URL
```

inside the `MainViewController.m`

```
self.webView.request.URL
```